# Monitoring Multiple tomcat instance on one linux server with Metricbeat and Jolokia

Tags: elasticsearch, tomcat, elk, metricbeat

How to configure below using the multiple agent port below, with metricbeat and jolokia to monitor multiple tomcat metric on One Linux Server...Would it be fine to configure the way below tomcat metricbeat events.module, can I get accurate separate tomcat metric in ELK?

cat /etc/metricbeat/modules.d/tomcat.yml

> -module: tomcat 
> metricsets: ['threading', 'cache', 'memory', 'requests']
> period: 10s
> hosts: ['localhost:8778','localhost:7777']
> path: "/jolokia/?ignoreErrors=true&canonicalNaming=false"